# Bitbucket API is there a way to return last/current deployed branch name for specific environment?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-api

I am building a small automation tool that will redeploy my last/current deployed branch again via api ,

looking through the document i could not find the right way to fetch my current branch name or anything related to it .

i tried the endpoint /deployments
i got a lot of data , but for somereason i can not see my last/current deployed pipeline in the list .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have found the way ,

[https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/environments/](https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/environments/)

then fetch pipeline uuid from the env u need and request the pipeline data via
/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pipelines/{pipeline_uuid}